# Objective-c: map a range

Tags: objective-c, c, math

I have a variable with values ranging from 0 to 4000, but need to convert the value so it outputs 0 to 1 instead.

In arduino, there's a function called, map:

```
map(value, fromLow, fromHigh, toLow, toHigh)
```

Is there something similar in objectice-C / C?

Thanks

Comment: The documentation (http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/map) includes the code for the function...

Comment: perfect. I'll use the function. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Divide it by 4000.0. ["Linear interpolation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) is what the math behind this is called.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in one line like this: `CGFloat result = ([your value]/ 4000.0f);`